# Can anyone locate the source of this hadith?

Tags: hadith, sufism

Once, when the Prophet (SAW) was sitting amidst his Companions (RAA), he asked: “In your estimation who possesses the most beautiful faith in all of creation?” On receiving the reply that they were the angels, the Prophet (SAW) said: “How is it that the angels not have faith when they are in the very presence of their Lord [and they directly witness the spiritual realities]?” Here the Prophet (SAW) is implying that while the intensity, depth, and completeness of the faith of the angels is beyond ken, their attainment of this faith is not such a remarkable accomplishment. Seeing that their first response was unsatisfactory, the Companions (RAA) gave a different response, and suggested that they were the prophets of Allah (SWT). To this the Prophet (SAW) said: “How is it that the prophets not have faith when Revelation is vouchsafed to them.” At this point, we can imagine that the Companions (RAA) must have hesitated somewhat before offering themselves as being the ones in all of creation who possess “the most beautiful faith.” To this the Prophet (SAW) replied: “How is it that you should not have faith when I am present amongst you?” Then the Prophet (SAW) said: “The ones in all of creation who possess the most beautiful faith are those brothers of ours who will come after me [and they will not be blessed with my company]. They will find pages containing the Book of Allah (SAW) and they will believe in what they find therein.” This tradition has been reported by Abdullah bin Amr bin Al-Aas (RAA) and narrated by Imam Bayhaqi (RA).

Source: https://jsr.shanti.virginia.edu/back-issues/volume-1-no-1-august-2001-mysticism-and-scriptural-reasoning-messianism-and-fulfillment/the-reality-of-tasawwuf-in-the-light-of-the-prophetic-model/

Comment: This tradition was not reported by Abdullah ibn Amr bin al-Aas as far as I can tell. I found it narrated by 'Omar ibn al-Khattab, abu Hurariah and Anas ibn Malik. And the word "beautiful" seems a bit strange as in Arabic it is "strange أعجب".

Comment: you mean, in which book it is?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/201514/

Answer (score 1):

The closest one seems to be recorded by *Al-Bayhaqi* in his book *Dala'il al-Nubuwwah* through *Amr bin Shuaib* from his father from 'his' grandfather (Abdullah bin Amr bin Al-Aas). The original Arabic text  is as follows:

> وقد أخبرنا أبو عبد الله الحسين بن عمر بن برهان الغزال وأبو الحسين بن الفضل القطان وأبو محمد السكري قالوا: أخبرنا إسماعيل بن محمد الصفار حدثنا الحسن بن عرفة، حدثنا إسماعيل بن عياش، عن المغيرة بن قيس التميمي، عن عمرو بن شعيب، عن أبيه، عن جده
>
> قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: أي الخلق أعجب إليكم إيمانا؟ قالوا: الملائكة، قال وما لهم لا يؤمنون وهم عند ربهم؟ قالوا: فالنبيون قال وما لهم لا يؤمنون والوحي ينزل عليهم؟
>   قالوا: فنحن قال: وما لكم لا تؤمنون وأنا بين أظهركم؟ قال: فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: إن أعجب الخلق إلي إيمانا لقوم يكونون بعدكم يجدون صحفا فيها كتاب يؤمنون بما فيها
>
> <sup>— [دلائل النبوة للبيهقي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7478/3003#p4)</sup>